# Scala Lift - Comet/Snippet sub directories

Tags: scala, lift

I was want to organize my files better and was wondering if I could use sub directories in the comet, snippet folders etc?

Something like:

```
code
    -> comet
            -> folder1
            -> folder2

    -> snippets
            -> folder1
            -> folder2
```

Thanks for any help, much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could do this.

Lift looks for Snippet/Comet by package name you set up in Boot.scala. For example, if your Boot.scala have `LiftRules.addToPackages("code")`, lift will find snippet under the package named `code.snippet`.

Since Scala doesn't like Java that require your directory structure match your package structure, it's totally fine to put your code under `code/snippets/folder1` and declare it belongs to package code.snippet just by using `package code.snippet` at the first line of your source code.

Answer (score 3):

And since Lift 2.4-M3, you can also have subpackages under snippet, or comet. See this [ticket](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/tickets/1061-allow-snippet-resolution-for-subpackages)

Basically you can have your comet inside a package

```
code.comet.folder1.MyComet
```

and in your html template you can have:

```
<div class="lift:folder1.MyComet">
    <p> some text to update using comet</p>
</div>
```

You can read this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/50c9c4bb25b1195a/) for how the feature came about.